# what is wrong with the code i found to include an image in a discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, image, discord.js, embed

I'm trying to send an image file through a discord.js bot. (yes I'm using if/else still, it's my first bot so I'm starting simple)

This is the code I have at the moment, but it's just not working. This is the only thing I've been able to find online regarding sending an image in discord.js using if/else.

```
} else if (message.content.startsWith ('!ping')) {
        message.channel.send ( {"files": ["C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Pictures\folder\image.jpg"]});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost good to go! There is just a little thing you should change.
I would highly suggest you create an images folder within your discord bot's folder, that way you can keep things a lot more organized, as well as you will encounter some issues throughout the way if you're attempting to gather images outside of the Discord Bot's main folder.

You have typed the `files` argument within quotes, which will not work as intended. Change your 2nd line to the following:
`message.channel.send({ files: ["./images/image.jpg"] });`
The `./images` directory can vary depending on where you actually locate the folder, but if you located it where all of the other folders are found, you should use the example shown above.

I hope this was helpful, best of luck with your coding.

Comment: hey so i did exactly what you said but it's still not working? i dunno if i messed up on the folder or something, but i copied your exact code and put a folder called "images" in my discord bot folder, with the image i was trying to use

Comment: Could you perhaps send a screenshot of where you located the images folder please?

Comment: What is the name of the image you are attempting to send? And are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: image is called "image" and im not getting any errors

Comment: If you are not getting any errors, and the name of the image matches the filter, the command or the function might not be getting recognized, could you send a picture or a link with the entire code where you placed the command?